# What is the white/cream colored plastic behind drywall in my wall?

Tags: drywall, anchor

I am running into a problem using self drilling anchors, where there appears to be a thin hard white plastic surface on the backside of the sheet rock.

This is the last pole of 6 that I need to install to the wall; the first 5 were no problem--I either used a stud or the self drilling anchors. On the last one, which is on a different interior wall, I find that the self drilling anchors go in a little then stop, when I try to put more weight behind the drill the anchors just spin then break.

In one of these holes I took a skewer and dug around a bit and I  see this white plastic something, I then pushed the skewer through the pilot hole I had drilled and it went right through into the wall cavity and out the drywall on the other side, so it is not PVC or the skewer would have hit the other side of it.

What the heck is it, and can I use the Zinc self drilling anchors instead ?

Comment: Can you provide a picture or two? That would be swell.

Comment: When you push on it is it movable? Close to a stud? What about the putter thermoplastic covering on the nmb or romex.

Comment: That type of rooms are we talking about?

Comment: Possibly related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/98266/95658

Comment: I can't get a good picture.  Some close to stud , others not. Will check and see how movable it is. Walls that are issues are  All interior rooms, a master closet, a pantry and a bedroom, AND not every wall in the room, just one. And yes the related post is EXACTLY my issue, but reading it no one had an answer. It's not metal, it's not a PVC pipe and it is just on the backside of one of the interior walls, not the one it is adjoining. I'm thinking some kind of fire precaution but can't find anything to support that. Still stumped :(

Comment: it could be a shower liner if this was previously a bathroom,